# Access viewDidLoad from a ViewController in didReceiveRemoteNotification method

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have a UINavigationController as the rootView of my Storyboard.

What I want to do is, when I receive a push notification, to call the "ViewDidLoad" method from the ViewController that is being showed (so the actual view of that NavigationController) but I can't access the NavigationController. Any ideas?

Comment: No, you do not want to call `viewDidLoad`. Refactor the needed code into another method and call that method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not call `viewDidLoad` directly. However, if you must, you could access the current view controller via:

```
[[[[[UIScreen mainScreen] keyWindow] rootViewController] navigationController] topViewController]
```